Can I drive in Albania with a Brazilian license without an IDP?
I have seen conflicting information about whether an IDP is required for Albania.
Here it says an IDP is required, here and here it says not required.
Brazil is part of the Vienna convention, I'm over 25, hold a B license for over 2 years, and my license is issued with English and Spanish translation.
This is a sample of how my driver license looks like (usually folded twice):


To rent a car? Or do you have someone which allows you to drive a car? In the first case often rental companies requires international driving permit, mostly it is due about categories you are allowed to drive.

If I drive it would be a rental a car. However, no rental mention this requirement. I often been asked by the rental agencies whether I had all documents to drive, because often they don't know the requirements from all different countries.

I've been able to rent from companies that officially require IDPs without anyone asking me for anything other than my national driving license. So, YMMV, whatever the official policy is. That said, IDPs aren't really all that expensive... Generally, unless there's an explicit agreement between Brazil and Albania, IDPs are required.

@littleadv countries party to the 1969 convention (as amended) accept foreign domestic permits matching the format listed in Annex 6 of the convention. That essentially means they should use the categories defined in the convention (e.g. the standard “less than 3.5 tonnes and less then 8 passengers” B category), and that all info listed should be in numbered fields matching the numbers in the convention (e.g 1=surname, 3=date and place of birth, etc.). Recent EU licensed use this format (they previously used the 1949 pink 3-part format). I think recent Brazil licenses use it but I’m not sure.

Could you include a picture of your license (with all person info masked)? Or point to a picture of the same version somewhere in the net? Wikipedia has past versions and a supposedly future version but not the current one. If it lists category B and has numbered fields (like the “future” version shown on Wikipedia) you should not need an IDP.

Thank you for looking into this, I attached in the question.

So in theory this should be acceptable without an IDP as it looks like (at first glance at least, I haven’t checked the details) it matches annex 6 requirements. But I have absolutely no practice with this (hey, I don’t even have a driver’s license!), so I’ll wait to see if people with more experience chime in before posting an answer.

I don't know about Brazil but, in most countries, it is easy and cheap to get an IDP.  Suppose that you get one and it was not needed - you have wasted a little time and money.  Suppose that you don't get one and do need one - considerable disruption to your plans.  Don't forget that the IDP does not replace your licence.  You must still bring your licence.

You can drive in Albania with your Brazilian driver's license without an International Driving Permit (IDP). Albania and Brazil are parties to the 1968 Vienna Convention on Road Traffic, which means they recognize each other's licenses. Your license, including English and Spanish translations, should be accepted. However, confirming with Albanian authorities (embassy) or carrying an IDP is advisable to avoid potential issues.
